# enum conflicts with UNICODE define

Tags: c++

I'm working on a C++ project (VC++) where "Use Unicode Character Set" has been selected.

[image]

This sets UNICODE and _UNICODE. Simultaneously, a third-party .h file that is included happens to include "UNICODE" in an enum, and these two are conflicting.

```
enum Encoding {
  ...
  UNICODE              = 17,  // Teragram Unicode
  ...
}
```

The IDE complains 'error C2059: syntax error: 'constant', because the UNICODE I want to use in the enum gets turned into the number 1. Is there any way I can escape the enum name? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a statement:

```
#undef UNICODE
```

before the enum. The problem here is that UNICODE will now be undefined and so for instance your TCHAR will become regular char for instance. This is a horrible name for an enum value. You will have to play around with the order of the includes quite a lot to avoid this.

Comment: Since `_UNICODE` would still be #define'd, you can `#define UNICODE` right after the enum if `_UNICODE` is #define'd.

Comment: I am assuming that the code in the third party library can not be modified. Anyway what you suggest should definitely help.

Comment: You can freely modify a library's .h files, since your code has to compile them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the efficiency, it's a real drawback of c/c++ enum.

Every time I face issues like this, I try the following 2 resolutions:

1. Add namespaces to guard them.
2. Add a prefix of the enum name: ENCODING_UNICODE

Comment: I agree with you. I think whenever we declare class, struct, enum, etc, we have to use namespaces to resolve this problem as well as for well-formed code.

Comment: It'd be less of a problem if people stopped naming things that aren't preprocessor macros in all capitals.

Comment: A namespace would not solve this problem, since `UNICODE` is a precompiler define and thus is not affected by namespaces. A prefix on the enum would be needed, if an `#undef` statement is not used.